# Is there a way to gray out a portion of an ImageIcon in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, imageicon, grayscale

I am trying to gray out a portion of the picture. normalImage is 100% colored while grayedImage is 0% colored. How can I generate grayedImage to be, let's say, 50% colored on the left, and 50% grayed on the right, or vice versa?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestPicture {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test Picture");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon normalImage = new ImageIcon("normalImage.png");
        ImageIcon grayedImage = new ImageIcon(GrayFilter.createDisabledImage(normalImage.getImage()));
        jl1.setIcon(normalImage);
        jl2.setIcon(grayedImage);
        jp.add(jl1);
        jp.add(jl2);
        jf.add(jp);

        jf.repaint();
        jf.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `BufferedImage#subImage` (you can use `ImageIO.read` to load the images) - you can then either create a third image which half copied into to lay them outside by side

Comment: What if I wanted to do something more complex, such as graying out an image in a clock form? Are you familiar with League of Legends? In the game, there are skills that have cool down. As time passes, it undarkens itself going clockwise. @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if I wanted to do something more complex, such as graying out an image in a clock form? Are you familiar with League of Legends? In the game, there are skills that have cool down. As time passes, it undarkens itself going clockwise

## You could...

Use `BufferedImage#subImage` to generate a "progress" slice of the color image and paint this over the top of the gray scale image, but this is only going to give you a linear progression, instead...

## You could...

Use a `AlphaComposite` to generate a mask of the progress, painting this over the top of the grey scale image

[image: Masked Progress]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage color;
        private BufferedImage gray;

        private Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
        private Instant startedAt;

        private double progress;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            color = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Progress.png"));
            // You don't need to do this, but my original image was transparent
            // and it was hard to see the fill effect
            color = fillImage(color);
            gray = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Progress.png"));
            gray = fillImage(gray);
            ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
            op.filter(gray, gray);

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startedAt == null) {
                        startedAt = Instant.now();
                    }
                    Instant now = Instant.now();
                    Duration runTime = Duration.between(startedAt, now);
                    progress = (double) runTime.toMillis() / (double) duration.toMillis();
                    if (progress >= 1.0) {
                        ((Timer) (e.getSource())).stop();
                        progress = 1.0;
                    }
                    System.out.println(progress);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);
            g2d.drawImage(progressEffect(), 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected BufferedImage progressEffect() {
            int width = color.getWidth();
            int height = color.getHeight();

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D og = img.createGraphics();
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            og.setRenderingHints(hints);
            og.drawImage(gray, 0, 0, this);
            og.drawImage(maskedEffect(), 0, 0, this);
            og.dispose();
            return img;
        }

        protected BufferedImage maskedEffect() {
            int width = color.getWidth();
            int height = color.getHeight();
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            Graphics2D og = img.createGraphics();
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            og.setRenderingHints(hints);
            // This will "overfill" the are so it occupies the entire image
            Arc2D.Double expose = new Arc2D.Double(-(width / 2d), -(height / 2d), width * 2d, height * 2d, 90, -(360.0d * progress), Arc2D.PIE);
            og.fill(expose);
            og.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
            og.drawImage(color, 0, 0, this);
            og.dispose();
            return img;
        }

        protected BufferedImage fillImage(BufferedImage original) {
            int width = original.getWidth();
            int height = original.getHeight();
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);
            LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                    new Point2D.Double(0, 0),
                    new Point2D.Double(0, height),
                    new float[]{0f, 1f},
                    new Color[]{Color.YELLOW, Color.RED});
            g2d.setPaint(lgp);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.drawImage(original, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
            return img;
        }

    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
        BufferedImage image = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
        image.coerceData(true);
        return image;
    }

    public static void applyQualityRenderingHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateMask(BufferedImage imgSource, Color color, float alpha) {
        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight();

        BufferedImage imgMask = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgMask.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(g2);

        g2.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha));
        g2.setColor(color);

        g2.fillRect(0, 0, imgSource.getWidth(), imgSource.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        return imgMask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got to incorporate some of your code into mine. I did find that using ColorConvertOp slowed down my program a lot, so I had to tweek it a bit. I ended up just using a black background as the filter, since some of my pictures were already grayed out on its own, so a grayed filter would not be as effective anyways. I do want to know, what is the purpose of using RenderingHints? I took it out and it produced the same effects.

Comment: First, the example is unoptimised, it's intended to be a seed from which you can implement your own solution. If I was doing this, I would cache the grey scaled instance either in memory or in a file and re-use as needed.  The original solution had the circle fitting within the image bounds, this generated a, unpleasant, image, the rendering hits help smooth this out.  Java's image processing defaults towards speed over quality, so unless you're finding a particular issue, I'd recommend using them (there are more, I've just a basic one which gave the immediate result I wanted)